# Store variables in a dictionary-like format

Tags: overleaf, variable

I am preparing a document that will have different versions with small differences.  I want to create the document in such a way that I can use a dictionary which maps different versions to the corresponding values of different variables in the document.

A dummy code of what I am trying to do:

```
\documentclass[12 pt]{article}
\usepackage{subfiles}

\newcommand{\username}{bob} %% I only want to change this line to create a different version

\begin{document}

ABC 

Name: <dict[\username][name]>

Age: <dict[\username][age]>

\subfile{user-info/\username}

\subfile{evaluation/<dict[\username][evaluation]>}

XYZ

\end{document}
```

Where the dict would contain the information:

```
{
    "bob" : {
        "name" : "Bob the Builder",
        "age" : 30,
        "evaluation" : "good"
    },
    "alice" : {
        "name" : "Alice from Wonderland",
        "age" : 20,
        "evaluation" : "good"
    }
}
```

And the directory structure looks like this:

```
root/
├── main.tex
├── user-info/
│   ├── bob.tex
│   └── alice.tex
└── evaulation/
    ├── good.tex
    └── bad.tex
```

This way, after writing all the information I should be able to create the version for Alice by just changing a single word in line 4 of the main document, and if I later change my mind and want to give a bad evaluation to Alice, I just need to change one value in the dict. So my question is how to create such a dictionary in latex?

I am fairly new to latex and using overleaf for creating the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a set of files to help you produce a pdf for each username, automatically.

Firstly, the `data.csv`

```tex
id,name,age,evaluation
alice,Alice from Wonderland,20,good
bob,Bob the Builder,30,goodname
```

Then, a `template.tex` like what you provides.

```tex
% this is `templatex.tex`
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}
% code making use of four predefined commands

ID: \id                 \\
Name: \name             \\
Age: \age               \\
Evaluation: \evaluation
\end{document}
```

Finally, a `main.tex`

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{shellesc}

\begin{document}
\csvreader
  {data.csv}
  {id=\id, name=\name, age=\age, evaluation=\evaluation}
  {%
    Processing \texttt{id=\id} \ldots{} done.\par
    \ShellEscape{%
      pdflatex -jobname='\id'
        '\def\noexpand\id{\id}%
         \def\noexpand\name{\name}%
         \def\noexpand\age{\age}%
         \def\noexpand\evaluation{\evaluation}%
         \noexpand\input template.tex'%
    }
  }
\end{document}
```

Execute `pdflatex -shell-escape main.tex` then you'll get `alice.pdf` and `bob.pdf`, which are the result of compiling `template.tex` with `\id`, `\name`, `\age`, and `\evaluation` pre-defined according to the corresponding rows in `data.csv`.

What exactly happens in `pdflatex -shell-escape main.tex`:

1. `data.csv` is input by `\csvreader` from [`csvsimple`](https://ctan.org/pkg/csvsimple) package.
2. `\csvreader` will then loop through the csv file, line by line. Four commands are defined each time before the loop body is used, which is set by the second argument of `\csvreader`---`id=\id, name=\name, age=\age, evaluation=\evaluation` (in the form of `<column name>=<latex command>`).
3. The loop body will execute `pdflatex -jobname='<pdf name>' '<code>\input template.tex'`.

The third step is the core. `-jobname` sets the name of output pdf, and `<code>` passes date. Creating an `\id.tex` file each time which contains required data also works.

To input `csv` file in LaTeX, `csvsimple` is not the only choice. Moreover, the first two steps can be easily rewritten in other programming languages.